# Sorting a python dictionary by one value, then two value in list values

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

struct product: sku, quantity, price, group

key: list(values)

```
dic = {'product1': ['m1', 2, 101, 'g500'], 'product4': ['m112', 2, 101, 'g700'], 'product5': ['m343', 2, 101, 'g500'], 'product2': ['m765', 2, 101, 'g500'], 'product3': ['m4346', 2, 101, 'g700']}
```

Order by key (or one value t[1])

```
OrderedDict(sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

How to sort the dictionary by group, then sku?

Need return data:

```
{'product1': ['m1', 2, 101, 'g500'], 'product5': ['m343', 2, 101, 'g500'], 'product2': ['m765', 2, 101, 'g500'],'product4': ['m112', 2, 101, 'g700'],   'product3': ['m4346', 2, 101, 'g700']}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
OrderedDict(sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda t: (t[1][3], t[1][0]),))
```